# Add RasPlex to existing Raspbian install?

Tags: raspbian, noobs, openelec

I have an 8GB SD card with NOOBS 1.4 and Raspbian.

Is it possible to add RasPlex on the same SD card and dual boot? If so, how?  Preferably without erasing what I already have installed.

The NOOBS boot menu has the option for OpenELEC_RPi2 but not RasPlex as such.

I read a forum post that said RasPlex is OpenELEC with a special build of Plex client, but I couldn't find anywhere to download that Plex client by itself.

Answer (score 2):

(Posting a self-answer with my results so far, since nobody has answered yet).

Firstly there's no simple way to turn a single-boot NOOBS into a dual boot.  You had to have selected the dualboot when first installing.  I decided to save my data, wipe the SD card, and download [berryboot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) which allows you to add new OSs at any time, and then reinstall Raspbian via berryboot.

Secondly: on the Raspberry Pi, the firmware is a part of the boot loader (It's not flashed into BIOS like on a PC).  RasPlex is a complete solution; RasPlex and Berryboot each have their own firmware module.

It turns out that the RasPlex development team often make their own firmware improvements, to fix playback glitches.  So for the best experience you have to use RasPlex in a single-boot scenario, i.e. if you want two boot types then get two SD cards and manually swap out.  The posts on the RasPlex official forum all assume that you won't be dual-booting.

Nevertheless I did manage to set up dualboot of Raspbian and RasPlex and have not had any issues so far.   It wasn't straightforward - I had to mount the RasPlex image and run some preprocessing on the contents to produce a file that is the right format to be accepted as a BerryBoot boot image.  I found those instructions by googling. I'll write another Q/A here on that soon.

Comment: This was roughly my experience, too - I've typically found it far easier to start with a Rasplex system and add other functionality to built it into a "full" install, rather than add Rasplex to Raspbian

Comment: @JonStory Since Rasplex now is LibreELEC (according to themselves), and LibreELEC's entire system is pretty much read-only, did I understand you correctly that you found it easier to combat the inability to install software on the system, than to add Rasplex to Raspbian? Or was it not read-only at the time?

Comment: It wasn’t read only previously, it just didn’t have many system binaries and utilities etc, but adding them was fairly easy (much of it automatic In fact, with apt dependencies)